# Is there a library/framework to human body tracking like kinect on Android?

Tags: android, computer-vision, kinect, tracking

I see some implementations on OpenCV, Matlab... but with Android I don't find. Is there framework or library to facilitate the development ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are still a few smartphones with depth cameras on board. So your question is not going to have an unique and really affordable answer... Anyway, there are some solutions from which you would like to start.

One example is proposed by HTC with their **HTC Dual Lens System**. If you are interested in this technology, you can refer to [HTC Dual Lens SDK](https://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk/htc-dual-lens-api) as a starting point.

But the most interesting and promising option is probably **Intel RealSense**, that is going to be integrated in several smartphones, by different vendors. If you are interested in developing Android apps to use this technology, you should take a look to [this forum](https://software.intel.com/it-it/forums/topic/562739) and follow the links to read more about the SDK.

Comment: Thanks, VitoShadow. So this area needs evolve.

Comment: @Vito Gentile i don't this your reply was in line with the initial request.

Answer (score 0):

ExtremeReality had an iOS and Android SDK for this - see http://xtr3d.com